# String.Format with slashes

Tags: c#, .net, string.format

String.Format doesn't work with "\":

```
String.Format("{ \"aps\" : { \"alert\" : { \"title\" : \"{0}\", \"body\" : \"{1}\" } } }", "aaa", "bbb");
```

What is the best way to insert title and text in this string ?

Comment: You appear to be trying to create JSON manually. This is a bad idea. Create an object that represents your data, then use a serializer such as [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to perform the serialization to JSON.

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't very descriptive. What are your expected and actual results?

Comment: The curly brackets are causing the issue.  Use two in a row instead of one. {{  and }}.

Comment: more correct way would be `var title = "aaa";
            var body = "bbb";
            var ss = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { apps = new { alert = new { title = title, body = body } } });`

Comment: @Eser You can even shorten that anonymous type to `new { apps = new { alert = new { title, body } } }` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's gonna be painful to use `String.Format()` with JSON. In addition to double-quote (`"`) characters, you also have to worry about the braces used for the format places holders (`{`). Even unescaped strings won't fix that.

But [there are](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) [numerous](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.aspx) [alternatives](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), including several options available via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=json) right from within Visual Studio.

Comment: And of course less than two weeks later I violate my own advice. I wrote some code on Friday that does this via `string.Format()` :/